# One single Nginx 301 redirect to HTTPS + with WWW subdomain

Tags: nginx, https, 301-redirect

please I don't know what I am doing wrong. I have removed a **default** file entry from */etc/nginx/sites-enabled* and there is only one enabled site:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;
    
    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    return 301          https://www.$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        root /django/example;
    }

    location /media/ {
        root /django/example;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/mydomain.sock;
    }
}
```

When I try a CURL test, it is still doing two 301 redirects, instead of one. It first redirects from **http to https** and then to www:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 24 Nov 2020 13:29:24 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Expires: Tue, 24 Nov 2020 14:29:24 GMT
Location: https://example.com/
...
...
Server: cloudflare

HTTP/2 301 
date: Tue, 24 Nov 2020 13:29:24 GMT
content-type: text/html
set-cookie: __cfduid=d750a6e7c1d415accb428ff6431220db01606224564; expires=Thu, 24-Dec-20 13:29:24 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
location: https://www.example.com/
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
...
...
server: cloudflare

HTTP/2 200 
date: Tue, 24 Nov 2020 13:29:25 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
set-cookie: __cfduid=d075d1d072fd35d4ec365037a68bb30cdb608224565; expires=Thu, 24-Dec-20 13:29:25 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
...
...
server: cloudflare
```

Is there something wrong, with my nginx configuration? Is possible to do one single 301 redirect from **http and non-www** to **https + www**?

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Do you see these responses in the access log? It seems suspicious that the responses claim that the server is "cloudflare" and not "Nginx".

Comment: Yes, I can see that in /var/log/nginx/access.log: 141.101.aa.xxx - - [24/Nov/2020:15:03:08 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "curl/7.68.0" and 141.101.aa.yy - - [24/Nov/2020:15:03:09 +0000] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "curl/7.68.0" these IPs looks like cloudflare IPs

Comment: This is normal to have two redirects. I forget the reason right now and will have to look it up again.

Comment: I recommend that you restore the default vhost in your configuration, so that most bot traffic won't hit your actual site.